# window.scrollTo() is not scrolling accurately

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollto

I am trying to scroll to a certain point on a page after enough data has loaded. Here is the code

```
while (document.body.scrollHeight < scrollOffset) {
    // this is not async, it adds placeholder items that get
    // populated later asynchronously 
    stuff.push(this._addStuff());
}

// scroll to previous location
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(scrollOffset);
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollOffset);
    console.log(window.scrollY);
}, 500)
```

The page scroll is set to manual like this:

```
if ('scrollRestoration' in history) {
    history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
}
```

The console logs report different numbers (the greater the scrollOffset, the greater the difference between expected and actual results), which leads me to think that something, but I don't know what, is preventing my scrollTo function from functioning properly. After this timeout runs, and the page has loaded, if I run scrollTo it runs accurately.

Comment: Some browsers are configured to maintain a scroll position relative to content on the page. Since content is being populated asynchronously, it's possible that the browser is following a specific element that is being moved by loaded content.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I think I have guarded against this with 
        ```if ('scrollRestoration' in history) {
            history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
        }``` Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: I'm talking about something else. In Chrome, you can configure it using chrome://flags/#enable-scroll-anchoring for example.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, hadn't heard of that. Disabling/enabling the flag did not have any effect though.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts have you some specifics solutions for this problem?